# Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource,

Tags: mysql, connection

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "Rachel";
$db = "hairdressingapointments";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected Sussessfully";
mysql_select_db('Hairdressingapointments', $conn) or die(mysql_error());
$sql = "SELECT `ApointmentDate`, `ApointmentTime` FROM `apointments` WHERE          `staff_id`=1 && `quantity`>0";
if(!mysql_query($sql)){
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo $sql;

mysql_close();

?>
```

spent hours trying to figure this out and im guessing its something so simple. getting back the following error:
  Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given in C:\wamp2\www\hairdressingapointments\TeresaApointments.php on line 15 which is,

```
mysql_select_db('Hairdressingapointments', $conn) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: You're mixing `mysqli_*` with `mysql_*`—they are two different, incompatible, APIs.  `mysqli_*` ("MySQL improved") is, perhaps unsurprisingly, an improvement on `mysql_*` (use of which has been deprecated.since PHP v5.5.0).

Answer (score 0):

1. You already connected to the database using

   mysqli_connect(...);

   So, you do not need

   mysql_select_db(....);
2. Also change the query to this

   $sql = "SELECT ApointmentDate, ApointmentTime FROM apointments WHERE staff_id=1 AND quantity>0";

   If you use SQLWorkbench or SQLYog or some other tool, you can enter your SQL and make sure it is valid before adding it to your script.
3. Also, make sure the table name is really

> apointments

and not

> appointments

I got this information from [php.net - mysqli_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)

Comment: Also take seriious note of eggyal's comment.  On http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php there is a Warning for mysql_query: This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.